# Good partition in locally compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact second countable metric space, endowed with a Borel probability space $\mu$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Question: Is it possible to find a countable Borel partition $\xi$ of $X$ such that

1. Any atom of $\xi$ has diameter less than $\varepsilon$
2. Any atome of $\xi$ has $\mu$-negligible boundary.

I know how to do this when $X$ is a compact metric space (then we may find such a finite partition) but it is not clear wether we can deduce the corresponding locally compact result.

Thank you.

Edit: assumption that $X$ is second countable

Comment: What if $X$ is uncountable discrete space?

Comment: True. We need the assume that $X$ is second countable.

Comment: Surround every element from a countable dense set (which exists by second-countability) by a ball with radius in $(\varepsilon/2,\varepsilon)$ (at least one of those has a null boundary).

Comment: Jorkug: is it clear that we must obtain a countable partition, from such a countable covering? Maybe this covering has a non-finite multiplicity. I think it could happen that for every $x$, the atom containing $x$ is $\{x\}$ itself, right?